# What does ngrok stand for?

Tags: ngrok

Recently, I got to know ngrok.
However, I cannot find where the name 'ngrok' come from.
Many software have interesting etymologies, and I wonder how ngrok was named.

Is it just ngrok?

Answer (score 4):

[This discussion](https://changelog.com/podcast/210) including Alan Shreve (the author of ngrok) may give some ideas.

In short, 'n' is just a starting letter of many network tools (just as **ngrep**) and 'grok' is just 'to grok'.

> so the name is kind of just a play on the word grok, coined by Heinlein, which is ‘to understand’, and ‘n’ because there are a whole bunch of other network tools that start with. It was kind of a play on ngrep.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. In general, we don't say.

~ an ngrok employee